# How to write a JS function that accepts and "forwards" variable number of parameters?

Tags: javascript, arguments, apply, variadic-functions

How do I write a Javascript function that accepts a variable number of parameters, and forwards all of those parameters to other anonymous functions?

For example, consider the scenario of a method that fires an event:

```
function fireStartedEvent(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...) {
    for(var i = 0; i < startedListeners.length; i++) {
        startedListeners[i](a,b,c,d,e,f,g,...);
    }
}
```

Especially since I have an event factory that generates these fire methods, these methods have no interest in knowing how many parameters a given event or its handlers consume.  So I have it hard-wired at 7 right now (a through g).  If it's any less, no problem.  If it's any more, they get cut off.  How can I just capture and pass on *all* parameters?

Thanks.

(Using jQuery or any other Javascript framework is not an option here.)

Comment: Is it possible to pass parameters as an array in JavaScript? That could do it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Solving this requires knowledge of two JavaScript concepts.

The first is the special [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/arguments) local variable that can be used to access the function arguments without knowing their name and it works like an Array. However, `arguments` is *not* an `Array`, but is "array like" -- having properties named `0..n-1`, where `n` is the number of arguments to the function and a `length` property -- object. A simple demonstration usage might be:

```
function f (a) { // can include names still, if desired
    // arguments instanceof Array -> false (exceptions to this?)
    var firstArg = arguments[0]
    // a === firstArg -> always true
    // iterate all arguments, just as if it were an Array:
    for (var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        alert(i + " : " + arguments[i])
    }
}
f("a","b","c")
```

The second feature is [`Function.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) which will invoke a function with a specific context (`this` when it is called) with arguments that result from the *expansion* of an "array like" object. **But see <sup>1</sup>**.

Thus, putting it together:

```
function fireStartedEvent() {
    for(var i = 0; i < startedListeners.length; i++) {
        // jQuery will often pass in "cute" things, such as a element clicked
        // as the context. here we just pass through the current context, `this`,
        // as well as the arguments we received.
        var arg = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        startedListeners[i].apply(this, args)
    }
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> While the ECMAScript specification only calls for an "array like" object, `Function.apply` *does not* universally work with an "array like" object and a number of common implementations *require* a proper `Array` object. The warning from the `Function.apply` link:

> Note: **Most browsers, including *Chrome 14* and *Internet Explorer 9*, still do not accept array like objects and will throw an exception [if a non-Array object is passed].** [FireFox was fixed in version 4.]

Thankfully, there is a relatively simply idiom to turn an "array like" object into an `Array` (which is ironic because `Array.slice` *does* universally work with an "array like" object):

```
var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
```

(And then `args` can be universally used in be used in `Function.apply`.)

Comment: doesn't seem to apply to what the asker wants.

Comment: I think this is *exactly* what the asker wants.

Comment: Thanks, pst.  The doc you link to is excellent.  I was torn between marking yours or Lauri's answer as the accepted answer because he took the time to apply it to my original question.  It was a coin toss.  I hope you understand.

Comment: @Andrew It's okay, I'm not that involved ;-) However, note that the sample code provided by Lauri is not correct. It may work in some browsers but it is flawed.

Comment: Lauri gave you the fish, but I think pst taught you how to use the fishing rod

Comment: Ah, I hate browser-specific behavior.  I switched to calling apply with args defined as `var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);` and it still works, presumably in more browsers.  Thanks for the extra tip, pst.

Comment: @tig Updated/corrected. Thanks for pointing out my undeveloped reply.

Answer (score 5):

I think "apply" and "arguments" are two JavaScript concepts you can use here:

```
function fireStartedEvent() {
  for (var i = 0; i < startedListeners.length; i++) {
    startedListeners[i].apply(startedListeners[i], arguments);
  }
}
```

Here's some code from my Firebug console I tried this out with:

```
a = function(foo) { alert('a: ' + foo); };
b = function(foo, bar) { alert('b: ' + foo + ', ' + bar); };

startedListeners = [a, b];

function fireStartedEvent() {
  for (var i = 0; i < startedListeners.length; i++) {
    startedListeners[i].apply(startedListeners[i], arguments);
  }
}


fireStartedEvent('one', 'two');
```

Comment: This code is not correct. arguments is array-like. It is not "an array". apply takes an array as the 2nd parameter.

Comment: pst, it seems to work for me, in that the method invoked using apply(null, arguments) gets called and seems to recognize all the distinct arguments.  Is there a problem I'm missing?

Comment: @pst - I did not know this - do you happen to have an example where the function I posted does not work?

Comment: @Lauri Arg. You challenged my assertion (and won; it works in Safari, Chrome, FF and IE6-8): I can not find a counter-example. Changed to an upvote. Thanks.